# Swift REST Request PUT Optional(502 Bad Gateway: Registered endpoint failed to handle the request.)

Tags: swift, xcode, rest, nsurlsession, nsmutableurlrequest

I'm trying to do a `PUT` request using Swift. In a REST client, when I try to do a REST request the following way:

In Body- x-www-form-urlencoded, I add `vote=1` and with id being taken in the param for example: `/user/:id`, it works!

I try to do the same in Swift code, it does not work and I get `responseString = Optional(502 Bad Gateway: Registered endpoint failed to handle the request.`

Here is my code:

```
var baseURL = "http://<domain>/user"
let putURL = baseURL + "/\(id)"

print(putURL)
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: putURL)!)
request.HTTPMethod = "PUT"

let putString = "vote=1"
request.HTTPBody = putString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
request.timeoutInterval = 1500

let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
    data, response, error in
    guard error == nil && data != nil else {
        print("error=\(error)")
        return
    }

    let responseString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    print("responseString = \(responseString)")
}
task.resume()
```

Comment: Generally 5XX error code indicate a server side failure. If the server is yours you can debug it to understand what went wrong. Be sure to check what headers do you send and what format are your parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to set the content type, e.g.

```
request.setValue("application/json; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
```

Without that, the server won't know what to do with the blob of random data that you just sent it.

I'm not saying that this is necessarily the only problem, but it is definitely a problem, and one big enough to cause the error you're seeing.